# How to emulate LaTeX Theorem environment with a Mathematica Style?

Tags: style, stylesheet, writing

( This has probably been asked before, but I found no Q/A's )
( Update: Changed Title 28/6 )

Mathematica has the Style 'DisplayFormulaNumbered', I want to find / create something like 'TextNumbered' ( think of the Theorem environment in LaTeX ).

The reason for asking is that I want to write a Notebook containing several Theorems with Proofs, and I want to number the Theorem cells.

Comment: Check `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "DisplayFormulaNumbered"}]` and everything related to the `Counter` keyword.

Comment: OK, thanks. There might be something in Counter.

Comment: I found no such thing as a Counter keyword ( I am on $Version = 12. ). Are you suggesting to somehow copy the "DisplayFormulaNumbered" definition to a "TextNumbered" definition? - If so, how do I do that, and what should I change?

Comment: I meant things like `CounterBox` `CounterIncrement` etc.

Comment: Are you suggesting to somehow copy the "DisplayFormulaNumbered" definition to a "TextNumbered" definition?

Comment: @niloderoock `"TextNumbered"` can inherit from `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"` and then you just have to make targeted modifications

Comment: Will the counters then work independent?

Comment: It doesn't look well if  half of the words in the title begin from capital letters so I edited the title. See https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html .

Comment: I wish you gave an answer instead of 'edit', but if editing is your thing: go ahead. I am not falling into a discussion trap.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've done this sort of thing with the following three styles, one for an unnumbered theorem, one for a numbered theorem, and one for the continuation of a theorem (after, say, a displayed formula, for which I used a different style).  The continuation style ensures the text aligns on the left.  (The `"Text"` style has a left cell margin of `66` and the paragraph indenting adds `24` to that.)  If all theorems (which for me included corollaries and so forth) are to be numbered, then the first two styles may be merged.

```
Cell[StyleData["Theorem", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Text"]],
 ParagraphIndent->-24,
 MenuSortingValue->10000,
 FontSlant->"Italic"]

Cell[StyleData["TheoremNumbered", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Theorem"]],
 CounterIncrements->"TheoremNumbered",
 MenuSortingValue->1000]

Cell[StyleData["TheoremContinued", StyleDefinitions -> StyleData["Theorem"]],
 CellMargins->{{90, 10}, {4, 8}},
 ParagraphIndent->0,
 MenuSortingValue->10000]
```

You have to type "Theorem" in the cell (and make it bold, if desired) but not the number. For the number, use the menu Insert > Automatic Numbering... and select "This counter object."  To refer back to a numbered theorem, you'll need to give each theorem a cell tag. Then click on the desired insertion point and from the automatic numbering menu dialog, select the appropriate tag.  Note that the number that appears in the `"DisplayFormulaNumbered"` style is one of the `CellFrameLabels`. That does not seem an appropriate place for a theorem number, so I settled for manual insertion.

Here is an example with the cell expressions following them.  (I did not have to edit the cell expressions, but the different uses of `CounterBox[]` might be instructive.)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Cell[TextData[{
 StyleBox["Theorem ",
  FontWeight->"Bold"],
 StyleBox[
 CounterBox["TheoremNumbered"],
  FontWeight->"Bold"],
 StyleBox[".",
  FontWeight->"Bold"],
 "  Any equation of the form...can be transformed in to an equation of the form (a parenthetical remark \
to show what happens when there is a line break)..."
}], "TheoremNumbered",
 CellTags->"ref:thm:normalform"]

Cell[BoxData[
 RowBox[{"\t\t", 
  FormBox[
   RowBox[{"x", " ", "=", " ", "4"}],
   TraditionalForm]}]], "DisplayFormulaNumbered"]

Cell["and perhaps other forms as well.", "TheoremContinued"]

Cell[TextData[{
 StyleBox["Theorem ",
  FontWeight->"Bold"],
 StyleBox[
 CounterBox["TheoremNumbered"],
  FontWeight->"Bold"],
 StyleBox[".",
  FontWeight->"Bold"],
 "  Any equation of the form...exist."
}], "TheoremNumbered",
 CellTags->"ref:thm:secondform"]

Cell[TextData[{
 "If we compare Theorem ",

 CounterBox["TheoremNumbered", "ref:thm:normalform"],
 " with Theorem ",

 CounterBox["TheoremNumbered", "ref:thm:secondform"],
 "...."
}], "Text"]
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that you can also set some `CellGroupingRules` on maybe the basic `"Theorem"` style and then set a `DefaultNewCellStyle` so that, e.g., every new cell will be a `"TheoremContinued"` if you are inside a `"Theorem"`. You can also use the `StyleKeyMapping` option to map `"Theorem"` to `"TheoremNumbered"` if you press `Tab` or something.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks, that's good idea.

Comment: You could also put the `"Theorem"` and `CounterBox` in the `CellDingbat` or `CellFrameLabels`. Also possible to have it auto fill that by clever and targeted usage of `CellDynamicExpression` as a FE thing.

Comment: @b3m2a1 Yes, I considered posting a `"Homework"` style that puts the `CounterBox` in the dingbat, but I didn't like that for theorems. However, it's a matter of taste and worth pointing out. I mentioned `CellFrameLabels` above; they seem to be centered, which seems an unusual place for numbering text. Above center might be the better of the four sides. I have a fear of too many dynamic expressions in stylesheets, but maybe such a fear is no longer well founded. Thanks again, though, you're helping me improve my own stylesheets. :)

Comment: Awesome answer, ( I knew there was a way in MMa ). Thank you very much.

Comment: @niloderoock You're welcome!